# Goldbach twin and cousin primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples, computational-mathematics, twin-primes

Good day.

My question is a counterexample for the following: Is every even number greater than 4 the sum of a number that belongs to set the cousin primes with another number that belongs to the set of twin primes?

Cousin primes (p,q) in the sense that if p is prime, then p+4 is other prime number.

I verify it up 1000. For example, and curiously, for 556=239+317 no there are much goldbach partitions that solve the question.

Comment: When you discuss the cousin primes, are you restricting this definition to only differences of $4$ between consecutive primes or is the distance unlimited?  Do you have some reason beyond a law of small numbers to believe that this pattern would continue to hold?

Comment: difference of 4 between two primes, as 3 and 7.

Comment: @abiessu, please can you check biggest number with java?

Comment: I don't have code readily available to check such a thing.  What have you used so far?

Comment: There is no counterexample upto $\ 10^6\ $.

Comment: Questions much simpler than yours are still open.

Comment: - Peter how check you the problem?

Comment: This would imply Goldbach's conjecture, so I don't think this is answerable in any useful way. It would also imply at least that there are either infinitely many cousin primes or infinitely many twin primes, which is also not known.

Comment: @mathreda I do not remember whether I ran over the twin-primes or the cousin-primes. Anyway I just checked the difference until I found a solution. In most cases, we quickly find a suitable representation, so $10^6$ is still well feasible with brutec force.

Comment: Checked all $n \leq 2.147 \cdot 10^9$ and still no counterexample.

Comment: 4 numbers come for free with each pairing (p,q),(p,q+2),(p+4,q),(p+4,q+2)

Comment: Hopefully not checking each prime,if so there's a shortcut to brute force.

Comment: If 2n-p isn't in a pair for Goldbach you can eliminate primes n+(-n) modulo p as well