# Goldbach's conjecture for odd numbers satisfying prime relations

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, examples-counterexamples, computational-mathematics, goldbachs-conjecture

Inspired by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3718847/goldbach-twin-and-cousin-primes) question and remembering Bertrand's postulate, I wondered.

> Does any set of random odd numbers satisfying Bertrand's postulate satisfy Goldbach's conjecture (i.e. that every even number can be written as the sum of two numbers in the set)?

In short, the answer is NO.

However, looking up Bertrand's postulate I found that there have since been [many improvements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate#Better_results) on the bounds.

As a set I took all primes up to $p=2010881$$=\textrm{nextprime}(2010760)$ and afterwards generated odd numbers $o$ satisfying
$n < o < (1+\frac{1}{16597})n$ up to $2^{30}$.

Surprisingly, this set satisfied Goldbach's conjecture (for $n < 2^{30}$) while the set is a lot smaller than the set of actual primes.

Since then I have generated $4$ more of these sets, each one satisfying Goldbach's conjecture up to at least $n < 2^{30}$.

My question is if there are counterexamples to this idea (that any such set satisfies Goldbach's conjecture)? If there are, what about some even [stronger results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate#Better_results) of the postulate? If not, a proof of this would also prove Goldbach's conjecture.

Comment: @nickgard indeed, sorry. The set used was with $n<2^{30}$ and it was a superset of the primes. Changed it in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Searching for $n < 2^{32}$ I have found a counterexample to the above question.

I have also found counterexamples performing this search with the
$n < o \leq \left( 1 + \frac{1}{\ln^3(x)} \right)n$
and the
$n < o \leq \left( 1 + \frac{1}{25\ln^2(x)} \right)n$
criterion.

However,
$n < o \leq \left( 1 + \frac{1}{5000\ln^2(x)} \right)n$
remains without finding any counter-example.

Comment: The primes in Goldbach aren't random. for all n not divisible by 3, we have the two primes adding to 2n are congruent to n modulo 3 or 2n-3 is prime

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee, interesting. However, if it holds for every possible set of random numbers it would also hold for the primes. Sadly, this way of generating random numbers with prime constraints does not seem to result in sets satisfying Goldbach's conjecture.

Comment: Let d be the distance from n to either prime we also get $$n^2+d^2\equiv 1\pmod {12}$$

Comment: in fact once you rule out 2n-p you can rule out distances congruent to n or -n modulo p

Comment: One statement of the conjecture of Goldbach is in theory: every composite is the arithmetic mean of 4 not necessarily distinct semiprimes.